# Read and push object in another object without array

Tags: angularjs, json, object

I am trying to check and push object in an object details from a JSON.

This is how my JSON look like

```
{
  "stylesheet": {
    "attribute-set": [
      {
        "attribute": [
          {
            "_name": "text-align",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "end"
          },
          {
            "_name": "end-indent",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "10pt"
          }
        ],
        "_name": "odd__header",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      },     
      {
        "attribute": {
          "_name": "font-weight",
          "__prefix": "xsl",
          "__text": "bold"
        },
        "_name": "pagenum",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      }
      ],
    "_xmlns:xsl": "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform",
    "_xmlns:fo": "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format",
    "_version": "2.0",
    "__prefix": "xsl"
  }
}
```

Now , I am trying to read the *attribute-set value [1]* ie; **"pagenum"** . HEre I am trying to check for more attribute value with name. If not present push it into that attribute set.

I don't have any problem in pushing into *attribute-set[0*] as it is in array . Here I got single object in *attribute-set[1].*

Tried this for attr-set[1], but throwing error - `Uncaught TypeError: $scope.contentObj.stylesheet.attribute-set[1].attribute.some is not a function`

```
//for checking font name
            var checkcontentPageFont = obj => obj._name === 'font-family';
            // check font family
            var checkcontentPageFont_available = $scope.contentObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][1].attribute.some(checkcontentPageFont);

            if(checkcontentPageFont_available  === true ){
            }
            else{
                 $scope.contentObj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][1].attribute.push({
                            "_name": "font-family",
                            "__prefix": "xsl",
                            "__text": "sans"
                          }
                          );                
            }
```

I can successfully implementing the above code if there is an array like ***attribute-set[0]***. How can I check this for single object. If not found push and an array will be created on *attribute-set[1]* ?

Answer (score 0):

In your example `$scope.contentObj.stylesheet.attribute-set[0].attribute` is indeed an array, while `$scope.contentObj.stylesheet.attribute-set[1].attribute` is an object, which prototype does not have `some()` method. I assume it is just a typo, so I changed `$scope.contentObj.stylesheet.attribute-set[1].attribute` to be also an array and now everything seems to work properly:

```js
const data = {
  "stylesheet": {
    "attribute-set": [
      {
        "attribute": [
          {
            "_name": "text-align",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "end"
          },
          {
            "_name": "end-indent",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "10pt"
          }
        ],
        "_name": "odd__header",
        "__prefix": "xsl"
      },     
      {
        "attribute": [
          {
            "_name": "font-weight",
            "__prefix": "xsl",
            "__text": "bold"
          },
          {
            "_name": "pagenum",
            "__prefix": "xsl"
          }
        ]  
      }
    ],
    "_xmlns:xsl": "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform",
    "_xmlns:fo": "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format",
    "_version": "2.0",
    "__prefix": "xsl"
  }
}

const checkcontentPageFont = obj => obj._name === 'font-family';

const checkcontentPageFont_available = data.stylesheet["attribute-set"][1].attribute.some(checkcontentPageFont);

if (!checkcontentPageFont_available) {
  data.stylesheet["attribute-set"][1].attribute.push({
    "_name": "font-family",
    "__prefix": "xsl",
    "__text": "sans"
  });  
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Have you modified the JSON manually ? If, so then it's wrong because the JSON is generating from other source. Bdw I have solved this issue. Thanks for you answer

Comment: Yes, I modified manually, assuming that both `stylesheet.attribute-set[0].attribute` and `stylesheet.attribute-set[1].attribute` should be of the same format: arrays. In your question the firs is array, but the second one is an object.